# contextthemewrapper cannot be cast to activity

Tags: android, fragment

in my small app i have a PageAdapter->Fragment->ListView->ImageView. On onImageClick  i want display my image in another Fragment (Fragment3), but when i load an image in my Fragment3 get an Exception

```
public class Fragment3 extends DialogFragment {
ImageLoader imageLoader;
...
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3_layout, container, false);
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFrag3);
    detail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewFrag3);
    imageUrl = getArguments().getString("URL");
    imageView.setTag(imageUrl); 
    activity=this;      
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getActivity().getApplicationContext());      
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageUrl, (Activity) activity.getActivity(), imageView);       
    return view;
}
...
}
```

and code which creates an Exception. When i create a fragment and add the ListView all passed ok, but when i create another fragment (child) and want to load Photo it fails.

code, how i create a child fragment, without PageAdapter

```
holder.imgViewImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView01);
        holder.imgViewImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();                   
                Fragment3 newFragment = Fragment3.newInstance();                    
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("URL", holder.imgViewImage.getTag().toString());
                newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                newFragment.show( ft, "dialog");
                Log.i("!!!", "Click on image");                 
            }
        })
```

here is Photo Loader Thread,

```
class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true)
            {
                if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                    synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                        photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                    }
                if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                {
                    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                    synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                        photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                    }
                    Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                    cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                    if(((String)photoToLoad.imageView.getTag()).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);            
                        //Exception contextthemewrapper cannot be cast to activity !!!
                        Activity a= (Activity)(photoToLoad.imageView.getContext());
                        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                    }
                }
                if(Thread.interrupted())
                    break;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

and Exception

```
02-09 08:22:57.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1449): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-114
02-09 08:22:57.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1449): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
02-09 08:22:57.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at com.example.ids.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:171)
```

Comment: where is this code Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext(); ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Activity a= (Activity)(photoToLoad.imageView.getContext());
```

You can't assume a `Context` can be casted to an `Activity`. Hence the exception: You're attempting to cast a `Context` that is in fact a `ContextThemeWrapper` to an `Activity`.

You can replace

```
Activity a= (Activity)(photoToLoad.imageView.getContext());
a.runOnUiThread(bd);
```

with e.g.

```
photoToLoad.imageView.post(bd);
```

to post a `Runnable` to UI thread message queue, similar to `Activity` `runOnUiThread()`.

Answer (score 95):

Similar case I have.
May be related question> [Accessing activity from custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129428/accessing-activity-from-custom-button/27434704#27434704)

I solve my case with this snippet.

```
private static Activity scanForActivity(Context cont) {
    if (cont == null)
        return null;
    else if (cont instanceof Activity)
        return (Activity)cont;
    else if (cont instanceof ContextWrapper)
        return scanForActivity(((ContextWrapper)cont).getBaseContext());

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From what I know, if a View that is shown in a Dialog, its context (access from view.getContext()) is actually a ThemeContextWrapper instance, which is probably not an Activity. To get the activity from the Dialog, you can use getOwnerActivity(), which returns the Activity that the Dialog belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin solution in addition to [kikea's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2724543/kikea) answer.

```
fun Context.scanForActivity(): AppCompatActivity? {
   return when (this) {
       is AppCompatActivity -> this
       is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.scanForActivity()
       else -> null
    }
}
```