# DecorContext cast Activity

Tags: java, android

I have a class NavActivity

```
public class NavActivity extends Activity implements OnItemLongClickListener {
....
}
```

In a function from another class, I have the following code:

```
    LocalActivityManager activityManager = this.getLocalActivityManager();
    Window window = activityManager.startActivity(tag, intent);

    final View view = window.getDecorView();
    Context decorContext = view.getContext();

    NavActivity nextActivity;
    nextActivity = (NavActivity)decorContext;
```

In previous versions of Android, everything has worked well. But in Android 7.0. it stops at this line and shows the following error:

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.internal.policy.DecorContext cannot be cast to xxxxx.nav.NavActivity**

Don't understand why casting from DecorContext into Activity does not work anymore in Android 7.0.

Comment: You can refer to this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657045/contextthemewrapper-cannot-be-cast-to-activity

Answer (score 1):

For this concrete example, I found the following solution:

I receive the needed activity by:

```
nextActivity = (NavActivity)activityManager.getCurrentActivity();
```

But in my project I anyway need to receive the correct View from Activity and then receive the View back from Activity.

Previously, getDecorView worked fine:

```
View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
```

And back:

```
Activity activity = (Activity) view.getContext();
```

But in In Android 7 (Nougat) DecorView no longer knows to which Activity it's related to. It's not clear what to do then.

Answer (score 0):

Because calling getContext on a View is not assured to return an Activity, it returns a Context.  Sometimes Views initialized from xml are passed in a WrappedContext-  a Context which wraps another context and overrides some values.  It is never safe to assume that a Context will be an Activity.  If it was working before then you got lucky-  I've seen this kind of failure all the way down to at least 4.x

Comment: You very rarely need to pass an Activity in, generally connect is good enough. If you really do, pass it in explicitly rather than assuming the context will be it