# How to finish an activity from Adapter class using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am trying to finish activity from adapter class while clicking `Recyclerview` item
using the code

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CountryCodeAdapter.CountryViewHolder holder, int position{
    CountryModel countryMode = countryModels.get(position);
    final String cCode = countryModel.getName();
    holder.llcountryCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),RegisterActivity.class);                        
            i.putExtra("countryCode", cCode);
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            ((AppCompatActivity)context).finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Also tried  this but didn't work

```
((Activity)context).finish();
```

And i get this error:

```
cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: The best way is creating callback for your adapter and finish activity in your fragment/activity which uses this recyclerView

Comment: https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetch Activity instance in Adapter constructor:

```
 public class MyAdapter extends IAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder,MyDS> {
    private Activity activity;

    public MyAdapter(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

  }
```

Comment: It is not best idea to keep activities in fields- can cause leaks

Answer (score 8):

Make an `interface` for the adapter (inside the adapter class)like this :

```
public interface YourAdapterInteraction {
        void onClickCountryCode();
 }
```

Make your `Activity` `implement` your `interface`, like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements YourAdapter.YourAdapterInteraction
```

Inside `YourActivity` :

```
@Override
    public void onClickCountryCode() {
        Intent i = new 
        Intent(this,RegisterActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("countryCode", cCode);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull                                                                                     
    CountryCodeAdapter.CountryViewHolder holder, int position{
      CountryModel countryModel = countryModels.get(position); 

      final String name = countryModel.getName();

      holder.llcountryCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context,RegisterActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("countryCode", cCode);
        context.startActivity(i);
        ((Activity)context).finish();
          }
        }
    });
```

instaed of :

```
Public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull                                                                                     
    CountryCodeAdapter.CountryViewHolder holder, int position{
      CountryModel countryModel = countryModels.get(position); 

      final String name = countryModel.getName();

      holder.llcountryCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new 
        Intent(v.getContext(),RegisterActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("countryCode", cCode);
        v.getContext().startActivity(i);
        ((AppCompatActivity)context).finish();
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You cannot guarante that the view's Context is always `Activity`. This can crash on API 19, because the view's direct context is a `ContextThemeWrapper`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27434760/2413303

Comment: this is only for activity if you are using fragment then it will happen

Comment: That answer is from 2011 and was added way before android.support.v4 started adding backward compatibility theme support.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface callback inside your recyclerView, implement the method in your activity and call the method when an item is clicked.

```
// in your recyclerView
public interface RecyclerViewCallback {
        void onItemClick(Item item)
}
// in your activity
@Override
void onItemClicked(Item item) {
        this.finish();
}
```